# Find all $4$ subspaces as the span of some basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

We are given a $3\times4$ matrix and it’s row echelon form and asked this question. I just need help interpreting it as I don’t really understand what my professor means. I understand the concept of finding a basis for the subspaces of a matrix. I think the wording is just confusing me, can anyone help me interpret this question please?

Comment: My guess would be they want bases for the column space, row space, and maybe left and right null spaces. Somewhere in your treatment will be an association of a number of vector spaces associated with a $m \times n$ matrix, and algorithms for computing bases of them. I agree that asking for just "all 4 subspaces" associated to a matrix, without more context, is not enough information.

Answer (score 1):

The question appears to be asking for a basis of the domain and a basis of the codomain such that subsets of the basis form bases for the subspaces.  Essentially, find bases for the subspaces separately and then put them together into a full basis for the domain or codomain.  For example, $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ would have $$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$ as a basis for the column space, and
$$\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$ is a basis for the null space, and the vectors $$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$ are orthogonal to the null space and complete a basis for the domain.